how to forcefully convert pd.Series in DataFrame to pd.Categorical
Why are both the x['A'] and x['C'] not pd.Categorical but pd.Series?
How to forcefully convert them to pd.Categorical? The pandas version is 2.2.2. Is this a bug for this version?
import pandas as pd

x = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "A": pd.Categorical(["A", "B", "B"], categories=["A", "B"]),
        "B": [1, 2, 3],
        "C": ["D", "E", "E"]},
    index=["A", "B", "C"])

print(type(x['A']))   #why x['A'] is still not pd.Categorical?
print(type(x['C']))

x['C'] = pd.Categorical(x['C'], categories=["D", "E"])
print(type(x['C']))   #why x['C'] is still not pd.Categorical?

###how to convert both of them to pd.Categorical?

However, in the following codes, pd.Series would be sucessfully converted to pd.Categorical. Why we cannot do the same conversion for pd.Series in a DataFrame?
c = pd.Series(["D", "E", "E"])
print(c.dtype)
print(type(c))

c = pd.Categorical(c, categories=["D", "E"])
print(c.dtype)
print(type(c))


try x.dtypes categorical concerns single cell, not the whole column.

x.dtypes are fine.  They are converted to category. But how to forefully convert both x['A'] and x['C'] to pd.Categorical so that I can use x['A'].categories and x['C'].categories without error popping out.  I know x['A'].cat.categories and x['C'].cat.categories work fine. I am just wondering if we can forefully convert the whole column to pd.Categorical?

x['A'].values and x['C'].values will give you pd.Categorical type.
print(type(x['A'].values))
print(type(x['C'].values))

result:
<class 'pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical'>
<class 'pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical'>


By calling type(x['A']), you're calling the type of the column 'A' within x, not the type of the values within. As @Adeva1 has stated in their answer as well, the correct way to get the data type of the values within the column woul  be to call .values():
print(type(x['A'].values)) # will give Categorical instead of pd.Series


A Pandas DataFrame holds Series, so when you pass it a Categorical, it converts it to a Series. The same goes for B, which gets converted from a list to a Series.
If you want to convert a Series to Categorical outside the dataframe, you can do that:
c = pd.Categorical(x['C'])
print(type(c))  # <class 'pandas.core.arrays.categorical.Categorical'>

Otherwise, you need to use the .cat accessor.
